# How could an Englishman be forced to fight for Austria-Hungary against his will during WW1?

Tags: military, world-war-one

I'm writing a novel set during the first world war. One of the characters is conscripted to fight for the Austria-Hungarian army while he is studying art in Vienna. How could this realistically go about happening? The final quarter of the novel deals with him facing political repercussions for this "betrayal" against his country.

- He lives in Vienna
- He is an Englishman
- He is an art student
- He is nineteen.
- He has no prior military experience.

Comment: Could he have been mistaken for an Austrian in some kind of Harry Buttle/Tuttle type incident? e.g. The authorities thought his English accent was fake and an attempt at "draft dodging" or something? Maybe then the bureaucrat involved in this mistake was afraid for his job (this wasn't his first mistake) and covered up the error.

Comment: Technically this is a hypothetical and possibly out of scope for this site; the question is well formed and has two answers, so let's not do anything, but please consult [help] to understand why we don't do hypothetical questions.  History is about what _happened_ historical sources & methods have trouble with what _might have happened_; that way leads to discussion, which we don't want.

Comment: Tale of two cities - mistaken identity. Nineteen year old art student might very well be filled with Romantic notions that might lead him to participate in the error.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Fiction authors should be incouraged to get the historical facts right. Much 'common knowledge' today still exists from fiction novels where history was  'adapted' to fit the story line.

Comment: Fully agree - but I want to make sure that new visitors to the site know that hypothetical questions are discouraged. This question works; it has generated good answers and contributes to a healthy interesting site.  Most similar questions diminish the site. Kudo's to @Noble.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and responses so far. Also, I really appreciate the kind words @MarkC.Wallace. I wasn't sure when asking my question if this was the best place to ask it, but I decided I would probably attain answers with the highest level of veracity if I asked here. I am grateful for the patience and the interesting discourse that has developed.

Comment: To clarify for @LarsBosteen, I was simply using "Germans" as a synonym for the Central Powers.

Comment: Is WWI a fixed *point* in time? Answer might differ whether you place that in eg August 1914, mid-1916 or Feb 1918? It'd also help if you define what you expect as "forced" (but a future answer might as well do that for you and enlarge that frame). To bypass 'hypothetical', perhaps ask for any known examples of similar 'cases'?

Comment: If he was a fluent German speaker and unable to prove his nationality?

Comment: @NeMo  As a foreign student he would have a past and be registered. As a minor, his parents would also be known. Passports were not that common as in the 1920's, but the registration was well developed in most of continental Europe.

Comment: Witnesses can be unavailable or not credible. Paper records can be destroyed, accidentally or maliciously. Fires are a good plot device for that. But we're getting away from the realm of history and into your novel, which is obviously your business rather than history stack's. For an example of someone denied their nationality, have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Bruce_Thomas. This was about 10 years later, but an example of how someone can be denied their citizenship. Good luck with the book.

Comment: @Noble I once read that at the beginning of WWI the Austrian emperor granted to officers born in neutral or enemy countries the rright to resign their commissions if they didn't want to fight for Austria,and some resigned and some did not.  I note that when the US Civil War started.the federal government permitted hundreds of officers and cadets to resign and go home to the south, even though it was obvious that many of them would fight for the CSA.

Comment: How did he get into art school?

Answer (score 13):

Based on the [Austrian conscription law of 1868](http://alex.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/alex?aid=rgb&datum=18680004&seite=00000437) and [militia law 1886](http://alex.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/alex?aid=rgb&datum=1886&size=45&page=325) **only** citizens could be conscripted.

The only exception would be for a foreigner to be conscripted would be with

- permission from the Emperor **and**
- permission of the government of the foriegner's citizenship
- with a minimal age of 20

base on the §§1,3,6 and 16 of the conscription law of 1868.

Since the United Kingdom declared war on the Austrian empire on the 14th of August 1914, it is unlikely that they would grant one of their citizens permission to join the Austrian army.

Even had they done so, it is unlikely that the emperor would have granted permission to a minor enemy foreigner to join the army.

To my knowledge, only the [United States conscripts residents who are foreigners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_the_United_States#Non-citizens).

---

Since the first step of conscription was the checking for eligibility in the registry (where age and citizenship would be noted), it would be more likely  that a UK citizen would be sent to [Internierungslager Grossau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internierungslager_Grossau), which is where English and French citizens were interned until 1917.

> After the English and French who had, up to then been quartered there, were moved from Grossau on April 29, 1917, the camp was temporarily vacated on May 1, 1917.  Among the internees was James Joyce's brother, [Stanislaus Joyce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislaus_Joyce), who had been transferred from the Kirchberg an der Wild internment camp.
>
> Arrested as a subversive on December 28, 1914, at the beginning of World War I, he [[Stanislaus Joyce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislaus_Joyce)] was interned by the Austrians at Katzenau, near Linz.

---

**Sources**:

- [Wehrgesetz vom 5. Dezember 1868](http://alex.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/alex?aid=rgb&datum=18680004&seite=00000437)

  - Pages 438, 439 and 441
- [Landsturmgesetz vom 6. Juni 1886](http://alex.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/alex?aid=rgb&datum=1886&size=45&page=325)

  - Page 325
- [Internierungslager Grossau – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internierungslager_Grossau) (German only)

  - [Stanislaus Joyce - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislaus_Joyce)
- [Conscription in the United States, Non-citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_the_United_States#Non-citizens)

Comment: It seems possible I suppose that if said 19yo were fluent enough in German, they might get pressed into service without a good chance to seek the proper legal recourse.

Comment: @T.E.D. Since the first step of conscription was the checking for eligibility in the registry (where age and citizenship would be noted), it would be more likly that a UK citizen would be sent to [Internierungslager Grossau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internierungslager_Grossau), which whrere English and French citizens were interned untill 1917.

Comment: @MarkJohnson This internment camp is very interesting!

Comment: The United States doesn't conscript anybody at the moment.

Comment: @Spencer But a **Selective Service** system still exists (even if not enforced). In June 2014, due to a *Y2K bug*, 27,218 conscription notices were sent out to peaple born in the 19th century. [Conscription in the United States, Non-citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_the_United_States#Non-citizens) **The Selective Service (and the draft) in the United States is not limited to citizens**.

Answer (score -1):

British nationality could be transmitted through descent in the male line. It would be lost through naturalization elsewhere.

Austro-Hungarian citizenship was granted, among other things, through descent, but I'm not sure if it is only through the male line.

An out-of-wedlock birth to an English father, later recognized, with muddled papers?

I've heard oral history from WWII of ethnic Germans living in Poland who got their citizenship and a draft notice after the German invasion. They self-identified as German, not Polish, so it is not quite the same.

Comment: Good question what happens in cases of dual nationality. At least since 1920, Paris Passport Conference, the citizenship of the country of residence took priority. How this was delt with before 1920: no idea.

Comment: Dual nationality or some sort of national confusion is a good idea, I was thinking of that myself.

Comment: @Noble For both Austria and the UK (until 1948), a wife recieved the citizenship of the husband and lost their original citizenship. So a dual citizenship would not be possible based on the parents citizenship.

Comment: Indeed Germany was conscripting ethnic Germans in many Eastern European countries during WWII. Note that ethnicity was well documented at that time, and German minority movements in Eastern Europe were often controlled directly by Germany (see eg Volksbund in Hungary). So your Polish example seems very different than the OPs situation.